# .net core: generate jwt token based on parameters passed into AddBearerToken

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-authentication

When I look into setting up JWT authentication for a web API I see the following process:

To your services:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    { 
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["secrets"]))
    };
});
```

Next step all documentations I have seen talk about is: in order to generate the token, use some helper classes and pass the configurations such as secrets and issuer **again**.
This never made much sense to me. Since the `AddJwtBearer` function has already taken in all configurations, isn't there a function as straightforward as `httpContext.GenerateJwt(new Claims[]{})` that would generate the token? Why would we need to use so much boilerplate?

I have been looking for a function like this since .NET 2.0. I create a NuGet to do exactly this (so I know what I am talking about is feasible and straightforward to implement). However, this NuGet no longer works with .NET 6.0. Instead of fixing my NuGet, I wanted to check if the .NET Core has a clean solution for generating JWT tokens yet.

Comment: Could you please tell me more details about your issue? The generate token need another codes which is not like services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer. This code is used to let the application know we will use JWT bearer authentication to protect the project not generate the token.

Comment: Yes, my question is why doesn't it also generate? For instance, with `addCookie` there is `httpContext.SignInAsync`. Granted token generation has additional parameter, like claims and expiration but it also has similarities like security key, issues and authorization. So, isn't there a function like I mentioned above that says `httpClient.GenerateJwt(new Claims[]{})` and provides the token?

Comment: basically, I'm talking about some function that does something like this:

https://github.com/neville-nazerane/Socially/blob/web_account/src/Socially.WebAPI/Utils/JwtCompleteExtensions.cs

Answer (score -1):

The AddJwtBearer token handler is only meant to be used in APIs receiving API tokens. There is no logic to generate JWT tokens. JWT Tokens are usually generated by your token provider (like IdentityServer).

The problem with generating your own tokens is the signature, you need to pass the public signing key to AddJwtBearer, for it to be able to accept the JWT tokens.

If you want to generate your own token for testing, then there is a tool called user-jwts.
[Manage JSON Web Tokens in development with dotnet user-jwts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/jwt-authn?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows)

I also have a set of blog posts about the JWtBearer handler here:
https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

By default, we use the JwtSecurityTokenHandler library to create and verify tokens

[image]

A more optimized version exists named JsonWebTokenHandler.

Comment: I am downvoting this since it doesn't answer the question. The first 2 paragraphs might could be comments under the question for discussion. The links are not even related to creating JWTs within the code

Comment: There is no feature to do httpClient.GenerateJwt(new Claims[]{})  in .NET and it makes little sense. You could instead then just send a random API key, and you are done. Properly use of JwtBearer involves a separate token issuer (like AzureAD or IdentityServer or simlilar). Also it involves signature keys that you should also involve if you want to do it right.   Theres an article here how to create your own tokens https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/creating-and-validating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core/?expand_article=1

Comment: My question does refer to the kind of code specified in the link you provided. 
The exact code within `GenerateToken` from your link could work with a function call of `httpClient.GenerateJwt(new Claims[]{})`. What makes little sense? You could send a random API key from where? could you elaborate on that scenario? Yes, you could use something like AzureAD but I could never understand why there isn't something out of the box for simple quick projects. There is already a `JwtBearer` function that supports authentication, just one more function GenerateJwt and you're done

Comment: It is all about what you want to achieve, and how secure it should be and what you need.  So it all depends. if you want to pass claims over to the API, then JWT is a good match. Then the question is how JWtBearer kan trust the JWTs , you then need to share the signing keys and managing keys in invidivual services is also a pain.

Comment: I never said anything about exposing an endpoint that takes in claims and returns a JWT. That would surely make less sense. I was just talking about having the function to be used internally, not exposed in an insecure fashion

Comment: Yes, hard to know when I don't have the big picture clear, but anyway , what is the actual question? Yes, you can make AddJwtBearer to accept any JwtBearer token, you can choose many different levels of "security" on top of that. You can do a lot of customizations in what you want to verify and how, in the TokenValidationParameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest 

the advantage with Jwt-tokens is that you can pass user-details as part of the token.

Comment: I'm sorry I see the confusion now. When I kept copy pasting and saying `httpClient`, I meant `httpContext.GenerateJwt`. The question was actually since `AddJwtBearer` lets you use `TokenValidationParameters` to pass the information in, why not have a `httpContext.GenerateJwt` that uses the same `TokenValidationParameters` and a timespan and generate the token

Comment: AddJwtBearer is pretty flexible when it comes to customization, and sure, you could have a function in the client that could automatically generate the token for you (like HttpContext...) It all depends on your security and functionality needs. I updated my answer a bit, perhaps you can accept it ? or what is the actual question now?

Comment: ok this gets closer to the question. The user of `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` is the "boilerplate" I was referring to. The token creation requires the use of "TokenValidationParameters" **again**. This would either mean repeating the properties or storing them as a singleton and reusing them. This boiler place each time seems unnecessary

Comment: Here is exactly what I was expecting .net to have out-of-the box: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/Socially/blob/master/src/Socially.WebAPI/Utils/JwtCompleteExtensions.cs

if the `AddJwtBearer` did whatever my `AddJwtBearerCompletely` does, and the `GenerateJwtToken` in the file came built-in, one could simply: create an endpoint that takes the username/password > use `UserManager` to get claims by username and password > generate JWT with a single function call **without** having to play around with `TokenValidationParameters` twice

Comment: Right now; as I said there are only two handlers included in ASP.NET Core and I would not trust any third-party token generators because creating a secure token generator/validator is hard. There are lots of examples of bugs in these types of libraries. You can always make a suggestion to the team responsible for tokens at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet